# Gradle build problem: Could not get unknown property 'libraries' in Caffeine Simulator

Tags: gradle, build, properties, simulator, caffeine

I used to work on my fork of Caffeine’s Simulator using Eclipse, and the project was compiled and built OK.

Suddenly I started getting the following error while running Gradle build:

```
Could not get unknown property 'libraries' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I indeed don’t understand the syntax “implementation libraries.X” in Caffeine's Simulator build.gradle dependencies.

To study the problem, I generated the project MWE in Eclipse, with the following build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation libraries.xz
}
```

This MWE gives the same error.
Once removing the line    *implementation libraries.xz*
the project builds OK.

I guess that "libraries" is a property / variable defined somewhere in Caffeine, but fail to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest of dependencies is defined in [dependencies.gradle](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/v2.8.2/gradle/dependencies.gradle). The root build file [applies](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/ddd207792f1a1d490b22cdb171762b3a003e73d4/build.gradle#L60) this to all of the subprojects,

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'biz.aQute.bnd.builder'
  apply plugin: 'java-library'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
  apply plugin: 'idea'

  apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/publish.gradle"
  apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/codeQuality.gradle"
  apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/dependencies.gradle"
  ...
}
```

The central manifest allows for referring to the dependency more abstractly, so that versions can be upgraded globally and reduces copy-and-paste issues.

It sounds like a local change to the build causes it to no longer import the manifest and the property cannot be resolved.